# For all prime $\ p > \ 2,\ p=2^x \cdot Ord_p(2)+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

For all prime $\ p\ > \ 2,\ p=2^x \cdot Ord_p(2)+1?\ $ Where $\ x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.\ $
Such as $\ Ord_3 (2) = 2, \ 3=2^0 \cdot 2 + 1$.
Is there some way to prove this?

Comment: Also see: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168165/relationship-between-this-conjecture-and-lehmers-theorem

Comment: $31 = 6\cdot \operatorname{ord}_{31}(2) + 1$

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample 31. Number 31 is the case of complicated, see oeis.org/A226014.  So if this combined with OEIS A226014, it will be more powerful.